# Какой частью речи является слово "на", глаголом или местоимением?

Tags: части-речи

Слово "на" является глаголом или местоимением?

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, о каком слове спрашиваете. Для русскоязычного вопрос выглядит очень странно. Если русский для вас не родной, то, возможно, вам проще будет задать его на английском на другом форуме. http://russian.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

> Какой частью речи является слово НА?..

Как я понимаю, речь идёт о частеречной принадлежности слова ***на*** в таких, примерно, контекстах:

*Не капризничай, **на** тебе конфетку!*

У Кузнецова в БТС ***на*** в значении "возьми, бери" названо частицей:

> **НА, частица.** *Разг.* Возьми, бери. ***На***, возьми книгу, передай брату. Передай мне масло. - **На**, дорогой.

Частицей ***на*** считается в таком значении и в *"Словаре наречий и служебных слов русского языка" Бурцевой*:

> **НА, частица**; *разг.* Сопровождает жест передачи: возьми, бери. ***На***, возьми, я же обещала. Не капризничай, **на** тебе конфетку!

Но не все лингвисты считают ***на*** в значении "возьми, бери" частицей. Так, в *"Объяснительном словаре русского языка"* Морковкина  ***на*** в этом значении названо междометием:

> **НА** и **НАТЕ, мжд.**, *разг.* ("на" -- при обращении к одному лицу, с которым говорящий на ты; "нате" -- при обращении к нескольким лицам
>   или к одному лицу, с которым говорящий на вы).
>
> Призыв к собеседнику взять, принять в руки то, что даёт, протягивает
>   говорящий…
>
> *Дай мне словарь. -- **На.** На тебе ключ, да смотри не потеряй, а то мы не войдём в дом. **Нате** вам газету.*

Comment: Ну можно, конечно, и так автора понять. Но у него-то, вообще "местоимение" - это-то с какого перепугу?

Answer (score 0):

"Не" - частица, "на" - предлог.

Answer (score 0):

Может выступить глаголом в значении "возьми". Чаще всего это приставка или предлог.